# FreeRADIUS, windows 10

Tags: radius

I'm following this example to setup a RADIUS server. I'm on Windows 10, and I don't have MD5 option. Does it matter? When I connect to the switch, the LAN says "trying to authenticate", so I'm assuming it's making the connecting to the RADIUS server?

http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/answers/Dynamic%20VLAN%20Assignment%20using%20RADIUS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The choice of authentication mode is only between you and the RADIUS server. It doesn't matter what the switch's documentation shows as the example – the switch will just pass through all EAP packets back and forth. Therefore choose the EAP method that you've configured in FreeRADIUS (usually PEAP).

Comment: ok, how do I know which methoad RADIUS server is using?  Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: That's something _you have to configure_ if you're the one setting up FreeRADIUS.